# Sevlte how to check changes in array bind to checkbox group

Tags: arrays, svelte

Using svelte I need to know in order to execute a function, every time than a checkbox group is checked. I'm using length's array property, but it doesn't work properly. Is there any best way to do it?

My code:

```
<script>
import Checkbox from './Checkbox.svelte';

let selection = ["b"];
$: console.log("selection: ", selection);
$: if (selection.length > 0) {
    alert('length is more than 0');
}
</script>

<label><input type="checkbox" bind:group={selection} value={"a"} /> a</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" bind:group={selection} value={"b"} /> b</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" bind:group={selection} value={"c"} /> c</label>
```

Or test in this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/008150e0625f43e58804eb0ebfec70f8?version=3.46.4)

Comment: Your REPL doesn't make a lot of sense to me. You never use `Checkbox` or `Radio` and `selection` is never changed. What is this REPL trying to achieve or show?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) `group` isn't a valid attribute for checkbox inputs. Note that `group` doesn't render in the DOM as well.

Comment: This seems to work, what is the problem ?

Comment: @StephaneVanraes I'm looking for a better way than selection.length > 0 to detect when array selection has changed, if is possible.

Comment: Can you do this @ToniBCN

`$: alert(\`new selection ${selection}\`);`

Comment: @OscarHermoso that's it! I've updated REPL example. `$: showConsole(selection);` is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, you could add as response? then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering from the comments on the original post:

> I'm looking for a better way than selection.length > 0 to detect when array selection has changed, if is possible.

When you are using `$:` bindings in Svelte, there will be an update for any variable changes in the the "top-level" statement.

This will alert whenever the value of `selection` changes:

```js
$: alert(`new selection ${selection}`);
```

Comment: Updated [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0c96111d3a3d49f4a3aec3ec29a28ee1?version=3.46.4)